# NSRangeException when I try to convert html string to attributed string in iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using the below code to convert html string to `NSAttributedText` and setting it to `UITextView`. It crashed for a particular Arabic text string when trying to set it as textfield's attributedText value giving the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSBigMutableString getCharacters:range:]: Range {6669, 1} out of bounds; string length 5267'
```

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

The Arabic string is

```
"<span style=\"font-size: 17; font-family: \'Roboto\';\"><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">الشروط والأحكام الخاصة باستخدام الموقع</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">إن دخولك واستخدامك للموقع الإلكتروني لمؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة \"الموقع\" يخضع للشروط والأحكام التالية، بالإضافة إلى قوانين دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة. دخولك إلى الموقع يعني موافقتك على هذه الشروط والأحكام، سواء أكنت مستخدماً مسجلاً أم لا. وبدخولك وتصفحك واستخدامك للموقع فإنك تكون قد قبلت، من دون قيد أو شرط، أحكام وشروط الاستخدام الواردة في هذه الوثيقة.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">تعديل الاتفاقية</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">لمؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة الحق في تعديل هذه الشروط والأحكام على أن يتم وضع إشعار بحدوث تعديلات على هذه الصفحة، وتدخل التعديلات حيز النفاذ بمجرد إحداثها مالم ينَصّ بخلاف ذلك. إن استخدامك المتكرر للموقع بعد إحداث تلك التعديلات يعني موافقتك على التعديلات. ويتعين عليك القيام بزيارات دورية لهذه الصفحة لمراجعة شروط وأحكام الاستخدام الحالية.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">التصرف</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">أنت توافق على دخول واستخدام الموقع لأغراض مشروعة فقط، وأنت مسؤول مسؤولية كاملة عن العلم والعمل بأي من وكل القوانين والأنظمة والقواعد والأحكام المتعلقة باستخدامك للموقع. وبمجرد دخولك إلى الموقع فإنك توافق على الامتناع عن: 1- استخدام الموقع من أجل ارتكاب جرم أو تشجيع الآخرين على التورط في أي تصرف قد يعد جريمة أو ينطوي على مسؤولية مدنية. 2- إدخال أو نشر أي محتويات غير قانونية تتضمن تمييزاً أو تشهيراً أو إساءة أو قذفاً أو فاحشة أو مواد إباحية. 3- استخدام الموقع من أجل انتحال شخصيات أو أطراف أخرى 4- استخدام الموقع لتحميل أي مادة فيها برامج تحتوي على فيروسات، أحصنة طروادة، أو أي شفرات حاسوبية أو ملفات أو برامج قد تعمل على تغيير أو إتلاف أو إعاقة عمل الموقع أو أي جهاز أو برنامج عائد إلى أي شخص يدخل إلى الموقع. 5- تحميل أو إدخال أو إرسال أو أي بث بخلاف ذلك لمواد لا يحق لك بثها بموجب أي قانون أو علاقة تعاقدية. 6- تغيير أو إتلاف أو شطب أي محتوى على الموقع. 7- تعطيل خطوط الاتصال الاعتيادية بأي شكل كان. 8- الادعاء بالارتباط مع، أو تمثيل أي شركة أو جمعية أو هيئة من دون أن تكون مخولاً بادعاء تلك العلاقة أو ذلك التمثيل. 9- نشر أو بث أي إعلان أو مادة دعائية أو أي شكلٍ من أشكال الترويج. 10- نشر أي مادة تتنافى أو تتعارض مع حقوق الملكية الفكرية للآخرين، 11- جمع أو تخزين المعلومات الشخصية عن الآخرين.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">التسجيل</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">بعض أجزاء الموقع لا تفتح إلا للأعضاء المسجلين و/أو تتيح للمستخدم طلب الدعم أو الخدمات إلكترونياً عبر إدخال المعلومات الشخصية. أنت توافق على أن أي معلومات تقدم لنا عبر تلك الأجزاء هي معلومات كاملة ودقيقة، وأنك لن تقوم بالتسجيل، ولن تحاول دخول الموقع مستخدماً اسم شخص آخر، ولن تتبنى اسم مستخدم قد ترى حكومة دبي الإلكترونية، وفق حرية تصرفها، غير مناسب.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">إنهاء الاستخدام</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">لمؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة كل الحق، وفق ما تراه مناسباً، في إنهاء أو تعليق دخولك إلى واستخدامك لهذا الموقع من دون إشعار ولأي سبب كان، بما في ذلك انتهاك هذه الشروط والأحكام أو بسبب أي تصرف قد ترى مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة، بملء حريتها، أنه مخالف للقانون أو مضر بالآخرين. وفي حال الإنهاء، لن يعود بإمكانك الدخول إلى الموقع، وستستخدم مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة كل وسيلة متاحة لتطبيق هذا المنع.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">وصلات المواقع الأخرى</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">بعض الوصلات على الموقع تقود إلى مواقع إلكترونية لا يتم تشغيلها من قبل مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة. ليس للمؤسسة سيطرة على تلك المواقع، كما أننا لا نقوم بمراجعة أو التحكم بالمحتوى الخاص بتلك المواقع. إن المؤسسة تلك الوصلات من باب التسهيل على المستخدمين، وليس لتلك الوصلات أي مضامين ترويجية خاصة بالسلع أو الخدمات أو المعلومات، وهي لا تنطوي على أي ربط ما بين مؤسسة محمد بن راشد ال مكتوم للمعرفة ومشغلي المواقع المتصلة. وعند اختيارك لوصلة خاصة بموقع خارجي، فإنك تكون خاضعاً للشروط والأحكام الخاصة بمالك/راعي ذلك الموقع الخارجي.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">المحتوى</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">تحتفظ مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة بالحق في مراقبة أي محتوى يتم إدخاله من قبلك، غير أنها ليست ملزمة بذلك. ومع أن المؤسسة لا تستطيع مراقبة كل ما يتم إدخاله على الموقع، فإننا نحتفظ بالحق (من دون التزام) في شطب أو إزالة أو تحرير أي مواد مدخلة من شأنها انتهاك هذه الشروط والأحكام. إن قوانين حقوق النشر والتأليف الإماراتية والأجنبية والمعاهدات الدولية تحمي محتويات هذا الموقع. وأنت توافق على الالتزام بإشعارات حقوق النشر التي تظهر على هذا الموقع.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">التعويض</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">أنت توافق على الدفاع عن، وتأمين، والحفاظ على سلامة مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة وكل موظفيها ووكلائها تجاه أي وكل مسؤولية قد تترتب على أي مطالبة ناجمة عن أي خرق من قبلك لهذه الشروط والأحكام، بما في ذلك التكاليف والرسوم المعقولة للمحامين. أنت توافق على التعاون الكامل في الدفاع ضد تلك المطالبات. لمؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة الحق في أن تتولى، على حسابها الخاص، الدفاع الحصري والتحكم في أي مسألة خاضعة، بخلاف ذلك، للتعويض من قبلك. وأنت توافق على عدم تسوية أي قضية إلا بموافقة خطية من قبل مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">تنازل عن الضمان</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">أنت تفهم بوضوح وتوافق على أن استخدامك للموقع أو أي مادة متاحة من خلاله هي خاضعة لمسؤوليتك الخاصة. ولا توفر مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة ولا أي من موظفيها ضمانة بأن الموقع لن يتعرض للتوقف أو أنه سيكون خالياً من المشاكل أو الحذف أو الأخطاء، كما لا توجد ضمانة بشأن النتيجة التي ستحصل عليها جراء استخدامك للموقع. إن المحتويات والأدوات على الموقع مقدمة لك على حالها، من دون ضمانات من أي نوع، سواء كانت صريحة أو ضمنية، بما في ذلك، ولكن ليس مقتصراً على، ضمانات الاسم، والصلاحية السوقية، والملائمة لغرض أو استخدام معين، أو الرواج.</p><h4 style=\"text-align: justify;\">حدود المسؤولية</h4><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">لا تتحمل مؤسسة محمد بن راشد آل مكتوم للمعرفة المسؤولية بأي حال من الأحوال عن الأضرار العرضية أو غير المباشرة أو الخاصة أو العقابية أو النموذجية أو الناشئة، والتي قد تبرز نتيجة لاستخدامك أو عدم قدرتك على استخدام الموقع، بما في ذلك، ومن دون حصر، ضياع الدخل أو الأرباح المتوقعة، أو ضياع السمعة أو ضياع العمل أو ضياع البيانات، أو تعطل الكمبيوتر أو عمله بصورة خاطئة أو أي أضرار أخرى.</p></span>"
```

I am using

```
// .. in Constants.swift
static let arDescription = "<style>font{font-size: 17; font-family: \"Roboto\"} ul,p,h4{direction: rtl;} rtl{direction: rtl;}</style><div class=\"font rtl\">%@</div>"
// ...

if let desc = data["description"] {
    let str = String(format: Constants.arDescription, desc).htmlToAttributedString
    this.detailsText.attributedText = str
} else {
    this.detailsText.text = ""
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please share the particular Arabic text string that is causing the issue

Comment: I have added the text string

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but why is the return type of your function `Optional` if you are never returning `nil` from it? Instead of `return NSAttributedString()` you should be doing `return nil` in the guard else branch. Moreover, if you don't actually handle the thrown error, you could simply return `try? NSAttributedString(data`, there's no need for the `do-catch`.

Comment: Moreover, I cannot reproduce your issue, both of your input Strings work just fine. Please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: I reproduced your scenario and didn't have any issues. The only think I can think of is there is something wrong with the encoding of the string which I'm not picking up after a couple of copy/pastes and being stored in SO db. Perhaps try pasting your string in and see if you have the same problem - if not there's probably something wrong with the original string or the encoding of your data.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am using `UITextView`. I tried hardcoding the string and it crashes.

Comment: Still no crash for me unfortunately with a `UITextView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension String{    
    func convertHtmlToAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to OP and to future readers of this Q&A) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting some code only.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using the below method to update the textview.

```
this.detailsText.textStorage.append(str.htmlToAttributedString ?? NSAttributedString())
```

Comment: Fixed what? Your `htmlToAttributedString` is never nil and already defaults to returning an empty `NSAttributedString()`. – I am glad that your problem is solved, but without some information what the actual problem was (and how it is solved) this Q&A is useless for future readers.

Comment: The problems is not with `htmlToAttributedString` returning nil. There is value and the value when assigned to the textview crashes it when I use `this.detailsText.attributedText`. Using the `textStorage`, it does not crash.